# Defining source encoding in standalone JavaScript (gjs)

Tags: character-encoding, import, gjs

*[this is a question about JavaScript not in web/HTML context]*

Is there a way to force any particular (i.e. UTF-8) encoding for source JavaScript files in gjs? I'm facing a problem where the first file run directly from command line (`$ gjs test.js`) is read as UTF-8, but any imported module is in some single-byte encoding, which is pretty much useless for non-English users.

Simple test case I have (the strings include fancy non-ASCII quotes).  File `test.js`:

```
print ("test “1”");

imports.searchPath.push ('.');
imports.test2.foo ();
```

File `test2.js`:

```
function foo () {
    print ("test “2”");
}
```

When the testcase is run as `$ gjs test.js`, it gives the following output:

```
test “1”
test â2â
```

As you use, directly invoked file `test.js` does produce correct output, while strings in the imported module get garbled. Is there any way to make gjs parse imported module as UTF-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is a [bug in gjs](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687095) and has been fixed recently (probably not released yet). With the fix it will work without any need to specify encoding.